# scp commands ran from mosquitto python callback have wrong context

Tags: linux, bash

I'm calling a shell script that performs an scp to a host to which i'm already authorised, so it **should not prompt** for a password, and it doesn't if i **manually** call the bash script.

It fails, and it asks for a password, if i'm calling the shell script from the **Python MQTT Mosquitto** callback, using any of these:

```
subprocess.check_call(['./test.sh', '-i', arg])
subprocess.check_call("./test.sh -i %s" (arg), shell=True)
```

The scp command is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no file1 root@other_host:/path/
```

Comment: How are you "already authorised"? Are you using `ssh-agent` or something like that?

Comment: Not an answer but logging on to a machine as `root` with ssh keys/password is very bad idea! `root@other_host`

Comment: If it asks for `password` prompt during ssh, you must look at logs in `/var/log/authlog` file, it might give few hints.

Comment: Yes. the public key was already copied using ssh-copy-id. So it doesn't ask for a password when doing scp manually or when calling the python script manually, but not when all the chain of actions is triggered inside the MQTT Moquitto Callback.